# Split a single column into multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I'm currently struggling with a query for our project management software (it's a school project).

I have the following Table:

```
 projectID     |    cID          |    value
---------------|-------------------------
1              |     3           |     321
1              |     4           |     442
2              |     3           |     999
2              |     4           |     799
```

And the final product should look like this:

```
      c1       |     c2
---------------|-----------------
      321      |     442
      999      |     799
```

Now, the problem is that there can be an infinite number of c1, c2, etc. and an infinite number of projects. So the table will get quite big (in both directions).

Is there a way to let the columns declare "itself"? If not, lets say I restrict the number of c1, c2, .. to 5, how can I do it? I tried something like:

```
select v1.value, v2.value from value v1, value v2
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe using conditional aggregation should get you your pivoted result:

```
select
  max(case when cid = 3 then value end) as c1,
  max(case when cid = 4 then value end) as c2,
  ...
from yourtable
group by projectid
```

Yes, there is a way to build dynamic statement within MySQL procedure by string manipulation and concatenation and then executing it using `EXECUTE`.

Comment: So you mean I should prepare the string "dynamically" within java, I get it. But that would mean that I have to first get all cid from the table, and then insert them dynamically.

Comment: I mean everything can be done within MySQL procedure. There is no need for Java here. Google it. Dynamic MySQL query. There are many answers on this matter on SO as well.